# Run time Error in executing a jar file on hdfs

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

What should i do further?
I have an error message when running this jar file on hadoop system.

> hadoop jar units.jar /input_dir/sample.txt /output_dir/result 
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
>       /input_di  /sample/txt    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)  at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:278)  at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:214)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)

Comment: Could you be less specific?

Answer (score 0):

From the [Apache Hadoop Docs](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/CommandsManual.html#jar) :

> Usage: `hadoop jar <jar> [mainClass] args...`
>
> Runs a jar file.

You are missing the fully qualified class name in your JAR command.